# Robot Framework Marking Test as Expected Failure or XFAIL

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Is there a way to mark a test as XFAIL in robot framework? 
I would like to execute the tests and if they have a defect tag associated with them I would like to mark them as XFAIL.

Is it possible to implement this using ResultWriter or any other module.

Comment: Can you describe what behavior you mean by xfail - something like the [pytest's decorator](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html)? If there's the defect tag and a test fails, what should happen? What if it passes (the tag was forgotten to be removed)?

Comment: Yes like pytest, the requirement is If I see 10 Failures I do not need to revisit those failures. So there can be different test status other than PASS and FAIL which is XFAIL. If it has defect tag and test passes then it can be marked as UPASS (Though its not my requirement as of now)

Comment: I don't think robotframework supports any other final status but the binary PASS/FAIL (yet), though I'd love to be proven wrong, I'd use yours two plus "skipped" heavily.

Comment: Would tagging them with the tag UPASS and XFAIL work for you as an alternative?

Comment: My requirement was if I tag them with BugID and they pass then they should be marked as UPASS and XFAIL otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I found this as a workaround that seems to be acceptable:  Add this to your test case:

```
# REMOVE WHEN FIXED!
Pass execution
...  This test fails and is a known bug! (add bug ref here)
...  Known Bugs
```

This way known bugs are forced to pass but are tagged as "Known Bugs" and are visible in the run log.

Comment: So what if there are know bugs and the tests passes,  I would still like to execute the tests to ensure that they should fail, and if they pass then its a UPASS.
Basically these are not tags or other metadata these are results.

Answer (score 0):

If having support for multiple test case statuses is important, have a look at the [Robot Framework plugin](https://github.com/kootstra/robotframework-allurereport#features) for generating XML files that are compatible with the Allure reports. Have a look here for an [example report](http://ci.qatools.ru/job/allure1_master-deploy/lastSuccessfulBuild/Allure_report/index.html#graph).

In the Allure reporting there are 5 statuses (Failed, Broken, Cancelled, Pending and Passed) in addition to 5 severity statuses (Blocker, Critical, Normal, Minor & Trivial). As Robot doesn't support these statuses a lookup is done on the set tags and based on those it determines the Allure Status and Severity.

In case Allure Report plugin doesn't work for you, perhaps you can use it's approach to generate a log file of your own through [Robot Listener functionality](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface). This is a set of [predefined events](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-2) that you can create a class for. Log Message and Message being two of particular interest to you.

The other one is a recently released project [Robot Background logger](https://github.com/robotframework/robotbackgroundlogger) that extends the standard logger class of Robotframework. This should provide some control over the formatting of the message.

Comment: Allure provide good reports and classification for but it was not my requirement. My requirement is to have more tests status like SKIPPED, XFAIL etc based on certain tags.

Comment: The Allure statuses are derived from set Robot Framework tags. In case this was not clear from the answer.

Comment: So is it possible if Give a TAG as XFAIL or SKIP and then I reports for these tags?

Comment: In regular robot script it is already possible to add a tag to a test case at run time through the use of the `BuiltIn.Set Tags` keyword. More details in the [Robot Framework documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Tags). This will also show up in the normal report/log file. Setting the following tags: failed, broken, cancelled, pending, passed will in Allure be considered status overriding and it will use those in its report.

Comment: My question was in Allure reports can I customize it to consider tags other failed, broken, cancelled, pending, passed?

Comment: Customization of the 5 statuses is not supported in Allure. The reporter library can be adjusted to map custom tags to one of the 5 fixed statuses, but that it it.